# Kestrel gives bad request after FIN and end of request

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a API made in Dotnet 6, running in a docker container and hosted on AWS.
The client is built in Wordpress and uses php curl to make requests to the api.

The Api is built with using minimal APIs and as much as I can see it doesn't do anything too fancy.

After going live with the API I did start notice strange logs where requests end with a BadHttpRequestException.

I have not been able to trace what is causing it but if we look at the server logs that traces the entire request we can see that the request is fulfilled and it sends back the response with a status of 200.

After that at row 18 it starts to close the connection, but at row 19 it starts to read the body again which after a while ends with a Bad request error at row 22 before the connection is stopped.
This error is not caught in my exception middleware so I'm lost to what to do or how to fix in.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Both Logs below are for the same endpoint on the api

Log with error in it

```
1 "Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" accepted.",
2 "Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" started.",
3 "{HostingRequestStartingLog:l}",
4 "{CandidateCount} candidate(s) found for the request path '{Path}'",
5 "Request matched endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
6 "The request has an origin header: '{origin}'.",
7 "CORS policy execution successful.",
8 "Successfully validated the token.",
9 "AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was successfully authenticated.",
10"AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was successfully authenticated.",
11"Authorization was successful.",
12"Executing endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
13"Writing value of type '{Type}' with status code '200'.",
14"Executed endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
15"HTTP {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded 200 in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms",
16"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" completed keep alive response.",
17"{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}",
18"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" received FIN.",
19"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\", Request id \"{TraceIdentifier}\": started reading request body.",
20"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" sending FIN because: \"{Reason}\"",
21"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" disconnecting.",
22"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" bad request data: \"{message}\"",
23"Exception": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.TryReadInternal(ReadResult& readResult)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.OnConsumeAsync()"
24"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\", Request id \"{TraceIdentifier}\": done reading request body.",
25"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" stopped.",
```

Log that is fine

```
1 "Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" accepted.",
2 "Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" started.",
3 "{HostingRequestStartingLog:l}",
4 "{CandidateCount} candidate(s) found for the request path '{Path}'",
5 "Request matched endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
6 "The request has an origin header: '{origin}'.",
7 "CORS policy execution successful.",
8 "Successfully validated the token.",
9 "AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was successfully authenticated.",
10"AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was successfully authenticated.",
11"Authorization was successful.",
12"Executing endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
13"Writing value of type '{Type}' with status code '200'.",
14"Executed endpoint '{EndpointName}'",
15"HTTP {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded 200 in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms",
16"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" completed keep alive response.",
17"{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}",
18"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\", Request id \"{TraceIdentifier}\": started reading request body.",
19"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\", Request id \"{TraceIdentifier}\": done reading request body.",
20"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" received FIN.",
21"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" disconnecting.",
22"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" sending FIN because: \"{Reason}\"",
23"Connection id \"{ConnectionId}\" stopped.",
```